# c++ - sorting a vector of custom structs based on frequency

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, frequency

I need to find the most frequent element in an array of custom structs. There is no custom ID to them just matching properties.

I was thinking of sorting my vector by frequency but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Easiest is to use `std::sort` and provide a lambda function to compare what you need.

Comment: Can you show an example of what a struct would look like, then an unsorted vector, and your desired sorted vector?

Comment: It almost sounds like you need to construct a histogram.  If that is the case `std::map` does a really good job.

Comment: I would use a key/value container for this, maybe unordered_map of ints.  The key would be the custom struct value (or any natural key it has, i.e. name, ID or something you make up) - 1st pass through the array bins into the map with the key, incrementing the int value.  Then you'd just find the largest value in the map.  That element's key will be the value that's most frequent.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking to sort a vector based on how often certain structs occur in the vector. i.e. - If you have these numbers, { 6, 4, 7, 6, 1, 4, 9, 6 }, and you want to sort them by how often each number occurs.

Comment: the sorted vector would be {6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 9, 7, 1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by frequency you mean the number of times an identical structure appears in the array.

You probably want to make a hash function (or overload `std::hash<>` for your type) for your custom struct. Then iterate over your array, incrementing the value on an `unordered_map<mytype, int>` for every struct in the array. This will give you the frequency in the value field. Something like the below would work:

```
std::array<mytype> elements;
std::unordered_map<mytype, int> freq;
mytype most_frequent;
int max_frequency = 0;
for (const mytype &el : elements) {
    freq[el]++;
    if (freq[el] > max_frequency) {
        most_frequent = el;
    }
}
```

For this to work, the map will need to be able to create a hash for the above function. By default, it tries to use std::hash<>. You are expressly allowed by the standard to specialize this template in the standard namespace for your own types. You could do this as follows:

```
struct mytype {
    std::string name;
    double value;
};
namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<mytype> {
        size_t operator()(const mytype &t) const noexcept {
            // Use standard library hash implementations of member variable types
            return hash<string>()(t.name) ^ hash<double>()(t.value)
        }
    }

}
```

The primary goal is to ensure that any two variables that do not contain exactly the same values will generate a different hash. The above XORs the results of the standard library's hash function for each type together, which [according to Mark Nelson](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/user-defined-hash-functions-for-unordere/231600210?pgno=2) is probably as good as the individual hashing algorithms XOR'd together. An alternative algorithm suggested by cppreference's [hash reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash/operator()) is the [Fowler-Noll-Vo hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function).

Comment: Maybe use `for(const mytype& el: elements)` to avoid creating a copy of each element.

Comment: You can just use `std::map` and not bother writing the hash function, unless you have enough elements that constant-time access makes a substantial difference.

Comment: can anyone show me how to create the needed hash function ? I'm new to hashing and also c++

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and the example provided in the ref, where you actually pass your own comparator to do the trick you want (in your case, use the frequencies). Of course, a lambda function can be used too, if you wish.

Comment: I don't see how you can do it in a single pass, as I think you need one pass just to know each element frequency. If you have an idea, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Your answer might be incomplete. I think the OP is asking to sort a vector based on how often certain structs occur in the vector. i.e. - If you have these numbers, { 6, 4, 7, 6, 1, 4, 9, 6 }, and you want to sort them by how often each number occurs, you can't just a simple sort.